# docker-compose volumes overwriting development folder files

Tags: docker, docker-compose, vscode-devcontainer, devcontainer

I'm trying to set up a development environment using Docker Compose, specifically with devcontainers for VS Code. However, I've encountered a problem where the files in my development folder are being overwritten when I bring the containers up.

Here's a summary of my `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  dev: 
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile

    volumes:
      - ..:/workspaces/flink-ci:cached

    command: /bin/sh -c "while sleep 1000; do :; done"  

  kafka-broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.3.2
    ...
    volumes:
      - code:/code

  pyflink-jobmanager:
    image: pyflink-kafka:0.1
    ...
    volumes:
      - checkpoints:/tmp/flink-checkpoints-directory

  pyflink-taskmanager:
    image: pyflink-kafka:0.1
    ...
    volumes:
      - checkpoints:/tmp/flink-checkpoints-directory
    
volumes: 
  checkpoints:
  code:
```

My expectation is that each volume is created separately from my development folder. Instead, when I build my development environment, `code` and `checkpoints` are created as folders inside the `.devcontainer` folder. All my other files are gone.

Before building, my project is structured like this:

```
.
└── project-root
    ├── .devcontainer
    │   ├── devcontainer.json
    │   ├── Dockerfile
    │   └── docker-compose.yml
    └── (other project files)
```

After the build, my project looks as follows:

```
.
└── project-root
    ├── .devcontainer
    │   ├── code
    │   └── checkpoints
    └── (other project files are gone)
```

I am still relatively new to Docker and I'm pretty sure I have just made a mistake in my configuration. Can anyone provide some insight or point out anything I might be missing?

Comment: Which directories are getting overwritten, in which context?  The `code` and `checkpoints` are Docker named volumes, and they are not connected to your host filesystem.

Comment: you should probably not use the relative '..' as a path for your first volume, try using '.test' to see what happen. I suspect the after build files are those cached in flink-ci and mounting the parent folder as a volume leads to your weird situation; that's just a guess though